# jQuery element binding is delayed, how to avoid it?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a few elements & then bind them to different methods, e.g.,

```
for( key in object ){
  var vals = someMap[key];
  var element = jQuery(parentElements[key]).find('.someClass');
  var markup;
  for( someKey in vals ){
      markup += "<a href='#' >" + vals[someKey] + "</a>";
  }
  jQuery(element).empty().html(markup);
  jQuery(element).find('a').bind('click', function(element){ alert(key); });
}
```

Now after running this code, I am able to create all the anchor elements, and so the alert should print the key within which the anchor tags were created, e.g., if I had 2 keys key1 & key2, so anchor tags were created inside the parentElements[key1] & parentElements[key2], so whenever I click on an anchor tag, I should have got alerted with either key1 or key2, depending on whose anchor tag i clicked. But the problem is that always key2 is alerted. So , I am thinking that the issue here might be that the binding is delayed till a click is performed, and when it is performed, the value of key alerted would always be the last key, i.e., key2.
I am not very sure what the issue here is, but since its always the last key being alerted, I have an impression that the binding is happening at the end, when both the loops have completed.

So is there something I am doing wrong, or should I do it in a different way? Any help appreciated.(maybe the question is not very explanatory, please let me know incase I should replace it with something else).

Comment: please post your code in jsfiddle.net it would help us to play.

Comment: What's "object" in your first for loop?

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: Thanks ThiefMaster & Subhajit - its just a js code, so I am not sure how you can play with this only as it needs some extra data.
@simon - object is a json object passed to this javascript via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using bind to attach events to elements added later, that's why it' snot working. Try using **live** or **on**...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for( var key in object ){
  var vals = someMap[key],
      element = jQuery(parentElements[key]).find('.someClass');
  element.empty();
  for( var someKey in vals ) {
      var anchor = jQuery("<a href='#'>" + vals[someKey] + "</a>");
      element.on('click', anchor, function(){ alert(key); }).append(anchor);
  }
}
```

Hint: always initialize your for-loops with var ... in ... or else you have global variables everywhere, which could interfere with other loops.